# What's the best practice when optimizing for a responsive mobile version of a website?

Tags: optimization, responsive-design

I want to exclude a number of items on my website when viewing it on a screen with a small screen resolution so I'm using CSS media queries to hide the items. But a Facebook Like box, for example, is still loaded in the background - a number of javascripts and css files - how do I prevent them from being loaded in order to decrease the page load time?

Right now I'm using PHP to check user agent and then simply exclude the code, but I wonder if that is the best way really. Over time I will have to change the PHP when new devices are introduced for instance. Is a script like Modernizr an option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a back-end and front-end mix would be best. You can use something like WURFL or even Apache Mobile Filter to make it easier to work on the back-end, and loading certain content only when  `is_tablet()` or `is_mobile()` are true.

On the other hand, I'd recommend checking jQuery image lazy-loading and share-button on demand loading (like techcrunch.com does). Those two fron-end techniques can really improve page load times (they cut almost in half the initial pageload time on my site).

Comment: Jeez, I see why techcrunch use lazy load, 32 js requests and an initial load time of appr. 20 sec! But lazy load is a good option for me, had almost forgot about that. And I'll definitely check out that back-end stuff, haven't tried them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, you could also use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (a front-end javascript solution) to detect something truthy (such as [if width > 320]) and then conditionally load some scripts etc based on that.